# Inserting URLs into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having troubles with an insert query with MySQL. Here's what I want to do:

in one of the fields in my table, I want to insert a bunch of URLs and their respective titles. I build up this query like so:

```
?content=<title of webpage>%%<url of webpage>%%<title of webpage>%%<url of webpage>%%
```

and so on, depending how many URLs there are.

The problem is if the URL contains something like "?var=somevalue" then my query breaks there since MySQL will think that I am declaring a new variable.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What code are you using to insert that data?

Comment: Does PHP's database tool set include placeholders?  What looks like a problem is actually a BIG problem.  In your current configuration you're exposed to SQL injection attacks, if one "URL" contained malicious SQL syntax.

Comment: I am constructing my query in Javascript and then using AJAX to pass it to a PHP function to insert into MySQL database

Comment: Okay, I guess it is bad practice to construct the query in Javascript. I opted to use the PHP form POST method instead with mysql_real_escape_string on the server side and it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should escape the sequence with a \

If you are using PHP an option is to use the following command (it has multiple forms):

- Procedural style

  ```
  string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )
  ```
- Object oriented style

  ```
  string mysqli::escape_string ( string $escapestr )

  string mysqli::real_escape_string ( string $escapestr )
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use placeholders in PHP (which I suspect is the language you're using)

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $value);

$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();
```

I grabbed that from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Placeholders, using prepared statements serve several functions, but one of them is to **separate data from code safely so that the problem you're describing goes away**.

Quoting from the site mentioned above:

> The parameters to prepared statements
>   don't need to be quoted; the driver
>   automatically handles this. If an
>   application exclusively uses prepared
>   statements, the developer can be sure
>   that no SQL injection will occur
>   (however, if other portions of the
>   query are being built up with
>   unescaped input, SQL injection is
>   still possible).